# CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC equivalent on AIX's xlC

Tags: c++, debugging, aix, xlc

I am trying to detect if I have a memory leak on my AIX xlC compiled object.  When using visual studio if I included CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC it would give me some printout information regarding memory leaks.  Does xlC have something similar to use when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using malloc() based heap allocation, you can try to use [MALLOCDEBUG](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-mallocdebug.html).

Third party tools like Parasoft's Insure++ would give a more indepth analysis but its not free.

Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: Valgrind, I think, has experimental support for some AIX versions.